# How to initialize AutoMapper in a multi-layer web application based on ASP.NET Core 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, .net-5

I am just trying to use AutoMapper for the first time in a project. My solution consists of the following projects:

- WebApplication: This is the actual ASP.NET Core 5 web application containing the controllers, files for the frontend (Angular) and so on.
- BusinessLogic: This contains the business logic for the application. In basically every controller method in the web application, one or more functions of the BusinessLogic will be called to get and/or send data to/from the frontend to/from one of multiple different data sources that are used by the application
- DataAccess: This is where all functions for sending or writing data are located.
- Model: This project contains the model classes which are used to represent the data coming from various data sources. The classes which were scaffolded by EFCore are also located here.

In older projects I always just used the scaffolded classes directly for everything. In most cases this worked fine but I no longer want to do this for various different reasons (for example because the classes are not always named how I want them to be named and modifying/extending them is also quite difficult or sometimes even impossible).
Therefore, I want to use AutoMapper to map the scaffolded classes into classes which I can fully control without depending on EFCore.

I already added the AutoMapper NuGet package to the DataAccess project since this is where I want the mapping to take place. Now my first question is: Where and how do I initialize it?
In tutorials I often see people initialize it for example in the Startup.cs file, but since I have no reference to AutoMapper in the web application project I cannot do this.

Obviously I also need to be able to use the AutoMapper functions in different classes inside the DataAccess project, so how do I get a reference to it in those classes? In examples/tutorials this is often done via Dependency Injection, but this seems to not really work well with my current architecture of the project. However, if there is an easy way to do this via DI in my solution then please let me know because I still don't fully understand how to work with DI in a multi-project solution.

Here is an example for how I'd like to use AutoMapper:

Controller method in the web application:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects()
{
    using (ProjectManager projectManager = new ProjectManager())
    {
        return projectManager.GetProjects();
    }
}
```

Manager class in the BusinessLogic project (simplified):

```
public List<Project> GetProjects()
{
    return projectDataAccessor.GetProjects();
}
```

Accessor class in the DataAccess project:

```
public List<Project> GetProjects()
{
    List<Project> projects = new List<Project>();

    foreach (TblProject tblProject in context.TblProjects)
    {
        Project project = <map tblProject into type Project>; // ToDo
        projects.Add(project);
    }

    return projects;
}
```

How do I initialize and use AutoMapper in order to do something like this?

Comment: You don't have to initialize AutoMapper. It's long ago that it only had a static API that needed one-time initialization. Now you can create mapping profiles anywhere, instantiate them and create mappers out of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to use dependency injection, you can handle this with a static bootstrapper class to setup the mappings and to access the mapper instance:

```
// DataAccess project
public static class MapperBootstrapper
{
    private static IMapper _instance;
    internal static IMapper Instance => _instance;
    
    public static void Configure()
    {
        if (_instance != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already configured");
        
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<ProjectProfile>();
                // Add more profiles and other mapping
            });
        _instance = config.CreateMapper();
    }
}
```

With profiles you can group your related mapping logic, such as mapping related to the `Project` model:

```
// DataAccess project
public class ProjectProfile : Profile
{
    public ProjectProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ProjectEntity, Model.Project>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.FullName,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => $"{src.Area}\\{src.Name}"));
    }
}
```

In your `Startup.cs` you can then use the bootstrapper class to setup the mappings as early as possible in the application's lifecycle (if you don't want the WebApplication project to reference the DataAccess project, you'll need an intermediate class in the BusinessLogic project):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    DataAccess.MapperBootstrapper.Configure();
    // ...
}
```

In your `ProjectDataAccessor` you can then use the mapper like so:

```
public List<Model.Project> GetProjects()
{
    var dbCollection = // Get data from the source
    
    return MapperBootstrapper.Instance
        .Map<List<Model.Project>>(dbCollection);
}
```

The examples are based on some dummy models:

```
// DataAccess project
public class ProjectEntity
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Model project
public class Project
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

To see an example in action, check out [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IBywGr).

Comment: It's not like I "really don't want to use dependency injection" but I simply don't know how that is gonna work across the multiple projects in my solution so I'd naturally prefer to not use it. If it is possible to use it without requiring a lot of refactoring then that also seems fine to me. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion!